# Is MoonlightDesktop suitable for porting wpf app to Linux?

Tags: wpf, mono, moonlight

I understand Moonlight is no longer supported by Xamarin, but I have a WPF application written on Windows that I would like to port to Linux. I want to avoid rewriting the UI code. I came across a Xamarin project called MoonlightDesktop (http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightDesktop) looks like what I need, but there's little discussion about it. Can I use this to port my app, if so, why has Xamarin not pushing it as one of their recommended cross platform UI libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moonlight is [dead](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/Miguel-Moonlight). So unfortunately this doesn't sound like a direction to take.

I don't know of any other cross-platform WPF-compatible toolkits either.

Comment: The source is available and if it's dead it doesn't matter. Mono needs something like WPF really bad, even if it's a small subset of WPF's functionality.  I was hoping this would be a cross platform story.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it can be done as described in this post:

http://walking-in-moonlight.blogspot.com/2011/05/run-wpf-applications-on-linux.html